# Converting a ForEach from JQuery to Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I'm looking to drop the Jquery dependency on a project I'm working on so I'm rewriting some code.

```
$.getJSON( "data.php", function( data ) {
  if(!Object.keys(data).length){
     document.getElementById('MOStatus').innerHTML = 'No';
 }
 else{
    document.getElementById('MOStatus').innerHTML = data.length;
    $redwarnings = 0;
    $amberwarnings = 0;
    $yellowwarnings = 0;
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    switch(this.warningLevel) {
    case "yellow":
        $yellowwarnings++;
        warningColor = '#FFE923';
    break;
    case "amber":
        $amberwarnings++;
        warningColor = '#ff9900';
    break;
    case "red":
        $redwarnings++;
        warningColor = '#cc0033';
    break;
    default:
    break;
    }
  });
```

I have rewritten it as:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'data.php', true);

request.onload = function() {
  if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
    // Success!
    var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
    if(!Object.keys(data).length) {
        document.getElementById('MOStatus').innerHTML = 'No';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('MOStatus').innerHTML = data.length;
    $redwarnings = 0;
        $amberwarnings = 0;
        $yellowwarnings = 0;
    for (var warningLevel in data) {
        switch(data[warningLevel]) {
            case "yellow":
                    $yellowwarnings++;
                warningColor = '#FFE923';
            break;
            case "amber":
                    $amberwarnings++;
                    warningColor = '#ff9900';
            break;
            case "red":
                    $redwarnings++;
                    warningColor = '#cc0033';
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }
    }

    } //Closes the else that comes into play if array is not empty.


  } else {
    // We reached our target server, but it returned an error

  }
};

request.onerror = function() {
  // There was a connection error of some sort
};

request.send();
```

The problem is that it counts the length of the data correctly but it doesn't seem to iterate over it and count the number of red, yellow and amber warnings.

I suspect I'm not referencing the keys/values in Javascript correctly - as you can see in the Jquery-dependent code, this.warningLevel works correctly but it won't work in the non-Jquery dependent code.

Comment: You can keep your original code and use `data.forEach(function (val, key) {...` (note that here, the order of `key` and `val` is not the same as with jQuery)

Comment: Unfortunately that was the first thing I tried and it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is an array of objects, so `data[warningLevel]` will give you an object: `switch`ing over it will not give you the colors you're looking for. Extract the property from the object first:

```
for (const { warningLevel } of data) {
  switch(warningLevel) {
    // rest of your switch code
  }
}
```

But a less repetitive option would be to use an object, whose keys are the colors, rather than 3 similar standalone variables:

```
const warnings = {
  yellow: 0,
  amber: 0,
  red: 0
};
for (const { warningLevel } of data) {
  warnings[warningLevel]++;
}
```

Then, eg, reference `warnings.yellow`, `warnings.amber`, and `warnings.red` instead of the standalone variables `$amberwarnings`, etc.

(since it looks like `warningColor` isn't being used, you can omit it)